# why Queues involves API design

Tags: java, rest, message-queue, restful-architecture

I saw some people when they write restful api, they divided the controller layer and Database access layer separately and let them communicate with each other through queues (like ActiveMQ). Why is that? Does this design improves throughput?
 Or any advantage of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: If someone is really fanatical about microservices, they might split the restful service into a separate application to the one that writes to the database. The advantage is you can make changes to (and deploy) one application independently of the other - but, as you notice, there is increased complexity and overhead for synchronising the operation of the (now 2, or more) applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason an engineer may adopt an architecture where a REST service will publish contents to a JMS queue is to avoid having the REST client wait for long running operations. The client instead submits data for processing (like saving the data to a database), and gets a quick response that the information was accepted for future processing.

For example one could use a `POST` to upload a large file:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @myFile.json localhost:8080/upload`

The REST service can place the contents onto the JMS queue and then immediately return an HTTP status code of 202 letting the client know that the message was accepted. It can also provide information to retrieve the processed data via the `Location` header.

`Location: 2112`

If the service can't accept the data for some reason, it would need to return an error code.

The REST API could allow for retrieval of the processed resource later via a `GET` method:

`curl localhost:8080/processed/item/2112`

If the item is not ready, the service could return a status of 202 (accepted). Later when it is ready, the service could return a status of 200 (OK) along with the data.

UPDATE: as noted below, if the ONLY thing you are doing is updating data in a database with the info received in the REST call then this is not recommended/useful. I answered this more broadly and assumed that other processing is required before persisting the data.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Now I am curious about the 202 scenario you described. Usually, how this would help? So on my client side, I should keep fetch the processed item status in a time interval until I get a success (200) or failed (like 500). Am I right? If this is the case, could you please give me an example how it being used in a real life case? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The `POST` upload API returns a 202 to make sure the client knows that the service has accepted the information and published it to the JMS queue. But if you don't like 202, you could return a 200. Any other response would be used to by the service to tell the client it did not accept the information and isn't processing it. A 400 would mean that the client sent bad info. A 500 would mean that the service has issues.

Comment: how one would design other aspects of the solution really do depend on what you are trying to achieve. in the answer I was just trying to give an example of how one might retrieve the processed data via REST. 

But the service could also publish the processed data to another queue that the original program/application reads from. Or maybe the original app doesn't care after it confirms the data was submitted. Maybe there is a UI and a user involved... etc.

Comment: thanks. I got the code that I mentioned started, use postman to send a post request to it and put a debug point on the data access service side (consumer side of the queue). Based on your explanation, I expect, the debug point will be hit but the postman request won't be blocked (should be completed immediately). However, I noticed the request on postman was pending for the response. Did I miss anything?

Comment: without seeing the code that would be difficult to determine where things went wrong. but that seems like a different question. this one asked why would someone possibly want to architect a solution w/ REST writing to a JMS queue.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a properly designed (from the ground up) architecture where what has been described would make sense. Databases and queues serve the same general purpose (storage), but databases are for long term storage and retrieval, whereas queues are for short term buffering.

You put things in a queue when there is a short term mismatch between available processing capacity and client requests. It would make perfect sense to queue requests to a micro service. Also, most web servers have a built-in request queue.

Simply queueing database operations means that your database is not capable of meeting your throughput needs. This is a permanent problem which a queue will not be able to solve. Requests should hit the database directly, and the web service code should call the DAL methods directly. Any queuing of database operations is best left to the database engine itself.